# jQuery toggle submenu

Tags: jquery

I need some help. I try to create a toggle submenu, using jQuery. However, submenu appears only for a few seconds and then disappears, when I click the parent `li`.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="">Hello</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a href="">Hello</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
                <a href="">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Hello</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery code

```
$(function() {
  $(".submenu").hide();

  $(".parent").click(function(){
  $(".submenu").toggle()
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` for current selected element and `find` the particular class inside the dom

```
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
        $(".parent").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // If you need to stop default action 
        $(".submenu", this).toggle(); // OR $(this).find(".submenu").toggle(); 
      });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/5/)

try as you asking in comment

```
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(e.target).closest("ul").is(".submenu")) {
            $(".submenu", this).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/13/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(e.target).closest("ul").is(".submenu")) {
            $(".submenu", this).toggle();
            $(this).siblings(".parent").find(".submenu").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

### [NEW Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/20/)

Comment: For facing this kind of issues.. jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/6

Comment: Ok, this works, but when i click a link in submenu thesubmenu disappears. I want to stay.

Comment: Is there any way when i click some parent ul the submenus of others to be close, if they were open?

Comment: Again malfunctioning http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/19/, @xarlap Why don't you prefer this.? http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/16/

Comment: @xarlap Dont asking one question with multiple answer, You have to ask new question , anyway we are give the solution for that ...it will create confusion for new answer visitors

Comment: @xarlap Usually crackpot's take wrong decisions.. I already told about this http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/19/ Anyway fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass this as the context to the selector,

```
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent").click(function (e) {
        $(".submenu:first", this).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

At this situation we need both `.preventDefault()` as well as `.stopPropagation()` needs to be invoked. So I recommend you to use `return false` to perform both of that operations.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ra6x3aak/)

---

```
$(function () {
    $(".parent a").click(function (e) {
        var elems = $(this).closest('li');
        if (elems.find('.submenu').length) {
            $(".submenu:first", elems).toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/14/)

---

For your new requirement use the below code,

```
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent a").click(function (e) {
        var elems = $(this).closest('li');
        elems.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
        if (elems.find('.submenu').length) {
            $(".submenu:first", elems).toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

### [DEMO NEW](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/16/)