# Toggle submenu list within an HTML table

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-table

There seem to be multiple questions / answers regarding toggling submenu items,

[jQuery toggle submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235928/jquery-toggle-submenu)

[jQuery toggle based submenu toggles all submenus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442684/jquery-toggle-based-submenu-toggles-all-submenus)

However, I'm trying to create submenu items within an HTML `table`.

On page load, I would like for the submenu items to appear open, like this:

[image]

You could toggle the submenu to become 'closed' by clicking anywhere within a `<tr>` with a `close-submenu` class (for test 5 or test 6):

[image]

I tried putting the submenu items (rows and table data) within divs, but my jQuery isn't working. And in fact, if I set the divs to `display: none`, they're still showing.

So I'm wondering - is it possible to achieve a toggle ability within an HTML table?

Here's what I've tried:

```js
function submenuClose() {
  $(document)
    .on('click', '.close-submenu', function () {
      $(this).closest('.submenu-list-container').removeClass('active');
    })
}

submenuClose();
```

```css
.table-container {
    padding: 20px;
}

#table-2 {
    padding-top: 0!important;
}

.my-card-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
    table-layout: fixed!important;
}

.exam-or-tutorial-tabs {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.exams-tab {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.tab-tab {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-tab.active {  
    background-color: #1481C3;
}

.tab-tab.inactive {
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

.tutorial-tab {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.table-heading {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}

.left-table-data {
    padding-left: 15px!important;
}

#special-table-heading-first {
    padding-left: 25px!important;
}

.my-card-table-heading {
    background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.special-table-heading-middle {
    padding-left: 13px!important;
}

.special-table-heading-last {
    padding-left: 25px!important;
}

.my-card-link-2 {
    color: #0e5b8b;
}

.table-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.complete-link {
  color: #666666;
}

.take-test-button {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #1481C3;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.take-test-button:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #096DA9;
}

.in-progress {
    background-color: #0e5b8b;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.in-progress:hover {
    background-color: #025398;
}

.taken {
    background-color: #A7A7A7;
    color: #E6E6E6;
}

.taken:hover {
    background-color: #A7A7A7;
    color: #E6E6E6;
}

.grey-row,
tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #F2F3F3;
}

.white-row,
tbody tr:nth-child(2n - 1) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.submenu-list-container {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-list-container.active {
  display: block;
}

.close-submenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-container" id="table-2">
            <table class="my-card-table"><!--CogAT Tests Table-->
              <div class="exam-or-tutorial-tabs">
                <div class="exams-tab tab-tab active">Exams</div>
                <div class="tutorial-tab tab-tab inactive">Tutorial</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-heading">
                  Exam Logo Here
              </div>
              <tr class="my-card-table-heading">
                <th class="my-card-table-heading left-table-data" id="special-table-heading-first">Test</th>
                <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-middle">Start Date</th>
                <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-middle">Status</th>
                <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-last">Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 1</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 2</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 3</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-white close-submenu">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 4</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">In Progress</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button in-progress">Continue</button></td>
              </tr>
                  <!--submenu-->
                  <div class="submenu-list-container active">
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
                      <td class="left-table-data">Part 1</td>
                      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
                      <td>Complete</td>
                      <td><a class="table-link complete-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
                      <td class="left-table-data">Part 2</td>
                      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
                      <td>In Progress</td>
                      <td><a class="table-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </div>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey close-submenu">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 5</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">In Progress</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button in-progress">Continue</button></td>
              </tr>
                  <!--submenu-->
                  <div class="submenu-list-container active">
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
                      <td class="left-table-data">Part 1</td>
                      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
                      <td>Complete</td>
                      <td><a class="table-link complete-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
                      <td class="left-table-data">Part 2</td>
                      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
                      <td>In Progress</td>
                      <td><a class="table-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </div>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 6</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">Not Yet Started</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button">Take Test</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                <td class="left-table-data">Test 7</td>
                <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
                <td><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link-2">Not Yet Started</a></td>
                <td><button class="take-test-button">Take Test</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

And here's a [Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/e9o24jwy/6/). As you can see, the submenu divs are displaying regardless of whether they're `active` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are at odds with HTML semantics :) so I fixed it. Below is my solution.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-submenu]');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const getSubmenuNumber = e.currentTarget.hasAttribute('data-submenu') ? e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-submenu') : '';
    const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-submenu-element="${getSubmenuNumber}"]`);

    numbers.forEach(number => {
      number.classList.toggle('active');
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.table-container {
  padding: 20px;
}

#table-2 {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.my-card-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
  table-layout: fixed !important;
}

.exam-or-tutorial-tabs {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exams-tab {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.tab-tab {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-tab.active {
  background-color: #1481C3;
}

.tab-tab.inactive {
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

.tutorial-tab {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.table-heading {
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.left-table-data {
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}

#special-table-heading-first {
  padding-left: 25px !important;
}

.my-card-table-heading {
  background-color: #E9E9E9 !important;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.special-table-heading-middle {
  padding-left: 13px !important;
}

.special-table-heading-last {
  padding-left: 25px !important;
}

.my-card-link-2 {
  color: #0e5b8b;
}

.table-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.complete-link {
  color: #666666;
}

.take-test-button {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1481C3;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.take-test-button:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #096DA9;
}

.in-progress {
  background-color: #0e5b8b;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.in-progress:hover {
  background-color: #025398;
}

.taken {
  background-color: #A7A7A7;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}

.taken:hover {
  background-color: #A7A7A7;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}

.grey-row,
tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #F2F3F3;
}

.white-row,
tbody tr:nth-child(2n - 1) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.submenu-list-container {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-list-container.active {
  display: block;
}

.close-submenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container" id="table-2">
  <!--CogAT Tests Table-->
  <div class="exam-or-tutorial-tabs">
    <div class="exams-tab tab-tab active">Exams</div>
    <div class="tutorial-tab tab-tab inactive">Tutorial</div>
  </div>
  <table class="my-card-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
          <div class="table-heading">
            Exam Logo Here
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="my-card-table-heading">
        <th class="my-card-table-heading left-table-data" id="special-table-heading-first">Test</th>
        <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-middle">Start Date</th>
        <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-middle">Status</th>
        <th class="my-card-table-heading special-table-heading-last">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 1</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
      <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
          <td class="left-table-data">Test 2</td>
          <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
          <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
          <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 3</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">Complete</a></td>
      <td><button class="take-test-button taken">Take Test</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu="1" class="my-card-table-row-white close-submenu">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 4</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">In Progress</a></td>
      <td>
        <button class="take-test-button in-progress">Continue</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu-element="1" class="submenu-list-container my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
      <td class="left-table-data">Part 1 submenu</td>
      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td>Complete</td>
      <td><a class="table-link complete-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu-element="1" class="submenu-list-container my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
      <td class="left-table-data">Part 2 submenu</td>
      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
      <td><a class="table-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu="2" class="my-card-table-row-grey close-submenu">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 5</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">In Progress</a></td>
      <td>
        <button class="take-test-button in-progress">Continue</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu-element="2" class="submenu-list-container my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
      <td class="left-table-data">Part 1 submenu </td>
      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td>Complete</td>
      <td><a class="table-link complete-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu-element="2" class="submenu-list-container my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
      <td class="left-table-data">Part 2 submenu </td>
      <td>Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
      <td><a class="table-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-submenu-element="2" class="submenu-list-container my-card-table-row-white submenu-item">
      <td class="left-table-data">Part 3 submenu </td>
      <td>Sept 9, 2021</td>
      <td>In Progress</td>
      <td><a class="table-link" href="">Take Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 6</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">Not Yet Started</a></td>
      <td><button class="take-test-button">Take Test</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
      <td class="left-table-data">Test 7</td>
      <td class="">Sept 9, 2020</td>
      <td><a href="" class="my-card-link-2">Not Yet Started</a></td>
      <td><button class="take-test-button">Take Test</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - there was something funny going on with the alternative between grey and white background colors in the rows, so I changed that in the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/427ebfnw/

But the idea was that we want the toggle to activate whenever the use clicks on _any_ part of an 'in-progress' row, not just on a 'continue' button... is that possible?

Comment: I have replaced now clicking on tr opens the submenu